# Fancybox inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, nested

I am displaying a form on fancybox. On click of cancel button I need to open one more fancybox: asking for whether you want to save or continue closing overlay.

I am unable to nest one fancybox inside other.
Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Fancybox is a single layer script, so you might not be able to overlay one on top of another. 
However,  you can invoke a new one after the first one closes with code like this

```
$('#ok-buton').fancybox({
    afterClose: function () {
        $.fancybox($('#confirm-button'));
    }
});
```